# Javax.swing: how to display updates to components properly?

Tags: java, swing

I'm writing a simple Knight's Tour program with a graphical display. I've already written it to work with the console, and now I'm trying to transfer that code over so that it works with swing. I've got a button whose Action Listener starts and operates the process. Here is the code:

```
askButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

            int[][] tour = getBoard(); // generates a matrix representing a successful knight's tour
            int count = 0;

            while (count < 64) {
                count++;
                Location loc = searchFor(count, tour); //gets the location of the int "count" inside the matrix "tour"
                board.setVisible(false); //board contains a matrix of JPanels called "grid".
                grid[loc.row()][loc.column()].add(new JLabel("" + count)); //adds JLabel to JPanel with the proper number
                board.setVisible(true); //reset to visible to show changes
                delay(1000); //wait 1000 milliseconds - one second - to allow user to view changes
            }
        }
    });
```

So that is the code. I want each number to show up individually with one second intervals in between, but as it stands, the frame becomes blank for a while and suddenly displays the results with all the numbers showing, once finished. Could someone please help? Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your `delay` method blocks the Event Dispatch Thread, avoiding repaints of those components. Take a look at the [Swing Concurrency Tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/) for more information on Swing and threads.

A possible solution for your problem is the use of a [Swing `Timer`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/Timer.html) instead of the `delay` method

Comment: Thanks a ton! I've never used threads before, so I'm not entirely sure how to work out the placement of the timer object and the call to .start(). I'll read up on threads and serializable, though. Thanks again.

Answer (score 5):

put all answers here together

1.don't call `sleep(int)`, `wait(int)` during code executed from [AWT / Swing Listener](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/handling.html), use

- [Swing Timer](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/timer.html) instead,

or

- all output to the Swing GUI must be wrapped [inside invokeLater](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/index.html) in code your nature

2.after `add` / `remove` / `modify` already visible container is required to call

- `revalidate()` and `repaint()`, thenafter `setVisible()`

3.`setVisible` must be wrapped inside `invokeLater` in code your nature

Answer (score -1):

When you are in that while loop, `repaint()` is never called. That would be why you don't see anything until the method ends.

Answer (score -1):

First of all, try to call revalidate() and repaint() after you make some change on the GUI. Second, I also had a GUI project which is similar to yours as my CSE assisnment.

During the process, I find that the GUI is not update simultaneously as I wanted. I tried many ways of working it out. The final solution is that give up using add JLabels or JPanels on the board(JFrame), instead, using setIcon or setText to have a better communication with the frame. Well, this is just my personally experience. Hope could of help for your project.